# Property 'to' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following code is throwing a `Property 'to' is missing in type` TypeScript error. Apparently, TS is not smart enough to realise that if `typeof url == 'string'` then the first props in the conditional are spread, which set the `to` prop.

I can't figure out a solution for this except by using conditional rendering, which I don't see very elegant in this case because of the common props.

Is there any way of solving this specific case without using conditional rendering?

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Tag = typeof url == 'string' ? Link : 'a'

return (
    <Tag
        className={u.joinLaden([
            styles.pill,
            active && styles.active
        ], ' ')}
        {...(
            typeof url == 'string' ?
            {
                to: url,
                onClick(event){
                    setActive(true)
                    close(url)
                    event.preventDefault()
                }
            } :
            {
                onClick(){
                    setActive(true)
                    onClick()
                }
            }
        )}
    >
        {children}
    </Tag>
)

interface BaseProps {
    icon: string,
    iconClassName?: string,
    secondaryIcon?: string,
    subtitle?: string,
    title: string
}

interface PropsWithUrl extends BaseProps {
    onClick?: never,
    url: string
}

interface PropsWithOnClick extends BaseProps {
    onClick: () => void,
    url?: never
}

export type PillProps = PropsWithUrl | PropsWithOnClick
```

Comment: You can't just dynamically call JSX/HTML tags like that. use `if/else` condition. eg ```if (..) { return <Link /> } else { return <a href="" .. /> }```

Comment: Yes you can. The code works perfectly and I used that pattern for years. The problem is TS complaining.

Comment: You can try to change this `typeof url == 'string'` to `Tag intanceof Link` when you destructure the props, so TS know that Tag is a Link or not.

Comment: Nice advice, it should work, but same. Or even worse, because now TS thinks that url could be undefined.

Comment: Is this a [mre]? I don't see definitions of `url` and we're `return`ing without being in a function.

Comment: Only added the relevant code. Just missing the wrapping function definition `function Pill({ ... }: PillProps){}` outside the return.

Comment: Tried wrapping it, didn't work.  Please just do it for us, so that it's a [mre] others can play with in an IDE without having to debug a problem you don't have.